# add datetime as string to a string after matching a pattern in vb.net

Tags: regex, vb.net, datetime

I have this string for example: "Example_string.xml"
and i would like to add before the "." _DateTime of now so it will be like:

"Example_string_20151808185631.xml"

How can i achieve it? regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can achieve that through the use of a look ahead.  For instance:

```
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace("Example_string.xml", "(?=\.)", "_20151808185631")
```

Since the pattern only matches a position in the string (the position just before the period), rather than matching a portion of the text, the replace method doesn't actually replace any of the input text.  It effectively just inserts the replacement text into that position in the string.

Alternatively, if you find that confusing, you could just match the period and then just include the period in the replacement text:

```
Dim result As String = Regex.Replace("Example_string.xml", "\.", "_20151808185631.")
```

If you don't want to just look for any period, and you want to be more safe about it (such as handling file names that contain multiple periods, then instead of `\.`, you could use something like `\.\w+$`.  However, if you need to make it that resilient, and it doesn't have to be done with RegEx, it would be better to use the `Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension` and `Path.GetExtension` methods, as recommended by Crowcoder.  For instance, you may also need to make it handle file names that have no extension, which even further complicates it.

Answer (score 1):

or...

```
Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension("Example_string.xml") + "_20151808185631" + Path.GetExtension("Example_string.xml")
```

Answer (score 1):

How about:

```
    Dim sFile As String = "Example_string.xml"
    Dim sResult As String = sFile.ToLower.Replace(".xml", "_" & Format(Now(), "yyyyMMddHHmmss") & ".xml")
    MsgBox(sresult, , sFile)
```

Comment: Rather than using the old VB6-style `Format` and `Now` functions, I would recommend using the standard .NET Framework methods (e.g. `Date.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmss")`).

Comment: Agreed - however the format capabilities of dot.net are pretty close to undocumented IMO, at least they are very well hidden and scatter.

Comment: I wouldn't say that.  Here's the documentation for the [standard date/time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/az4se3k1.aspx) and the [custom date/time formats](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx).